# Coalesced access in the following matrix copy kernel

Tags: cuda, gpu

The following kernel performs matrix copy that I came across in this article:
https://devblogs.nvidia.com/efficient-matrix-transpose-cuda-cc/

```
__global__ void copy(float *odata, const float *idata)
{
  int x = blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.x;
  int y = blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.y;
  int width = gridDim.x * TILE_DIM;

  for (int j = 0; j < TILE_DIM; j+= BLOCK_ROWS)
    odata[(y+j)*width + x] = idata[(y+j)*width + x];
}
```

I am confused with the notation used. From what I understand, the data is in row-major format. "y" corresponds to rows and "x" corresponds to columns. So, the linear index is calculated as data[y][x] = data[y*width+x];

How is odata[(y+j)*width + x] coalesced? In row-major, elements in the same row are in successive locations. So, accessing elements in the fashion, (y,x) (y,x+1) (y,x+2) ... is contiguous.

However "j" above is added to "y" which does not seem coalesced.
Is my understanding of the notation incorrect or am I missing something here?

Comment: every thread in the warp has the same value for `j`.  A really simple way to assess whether access will be coalesced in complicated indexing is to ask whether `threadIdx.x` component is multiplied by anything, anywhere, or not.  If it is not, the access will be coalesced.  If it is the access will not be.  In your example code, the indexing is such that `threadIdx.x` is not multiplied by anything.  It will coalesce.  Ignore `j`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coalescing memory transactions only requires that threads from the same warp read and write into a contiguous block of memory which can be served by a single transaction. Your code

```
int x = blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.x;
int y = blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.y;
odata[(y+j)*width + x] = idata[(y+j)*width + x];
```

produces coalesced access because `j` is constant across every thread in a warp. So the access patterns become:

```
0. (y * width);             (y * width + 1);             (y * width + 2); .....
1. (y * width + width);     (y * width + width + 1);     (y * width + width + 2); .....
2. (y * width + 2 * width); (y * width + 2 * width + 1); (y * width + 2 * width + 2); .....
```

Within each warp at any value of J access is still sequential elements with memory, so reads and writes will coalesce.